# Distinguish Subclass inside Constructor

Tags: java, class, constructor, processing, subclass

I am making a program using the Processing API for java.
I want to be able to pass objects into a class constructor and have different things happen depending on which subclass the object is of. I'm hoping to do this by using an overloaded constructor.

In this code, the Asteroid class checks each object in the Projectiles arrayList to see if it has collided with the asteroid.

```
      void checkProjectiles() {

    for (int index=0; index<Projectiles.size (); index++) {
      if (sq(Projectiles.get(index).xPos - posX) + sq(Projectiles.get(index).yPos - posY) < sq(size)) { //if within the a circle radius of size from centre of roid

        Collision newCollision;
        newCollision = new Collision(Projectiles.get(index), this);
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the current constructor for my Collision class. How can I alter this to distinguish which subclass is passed into it?

```
    class Collision {
  Asteroid destroyedRoid;
  Projectile collisionProjectile;
  //in case of a laser
  Collision(Projectile Laser, Asteroid collisionAsteroid) {
    destroyedRoid = collisionAsteroid;
    collisionProjectile = Laser;
    //remove laser
    Projectiles.remove(collisionProjectile);
    //create 2 new asteroids half the size
    Asteroids.add(new Asteroid(destroyedRoid.posX, destroyedRoid.posY, 0, 0.5, destroyedRoid.size/2));
    Asteroids.add(new Asteroid(destroyedRoid.posX, destroyedRoid.posY, 0, -0.5, destroyedRoid.size/2));
    //remove destroyed asteroid
    Asteroids.remove(destroyedRoid);
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which parameter do you think can contain subtypes?  `Projectile` or the `Asteroid`?  Either way, try this:

If you know the possible set of the subtypes, then `instanceof` checks will tell you if the given object is an instance of a specific type.

```
object instanceof Type
```

This would return a `boolean` that would tell you if the `object` is an instance of the `Type` or not.

However for the sake of extensibility, you should not do such `instanceof` checks to achieve what you want to - you should rather let all the subtypes implement a method that does what you want to and polymorphically call the method at runtime which would invoke the method on the correct type. This helps promote extensibility and reduce rework.

Read up `"Open for extension; closed for modification"` principle from the `Effective Java 2nd edition`.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like it could suit my purposes. It's subclasses of Projectile that I'm trying to distinguish. I was messing around with .getClass before, your suggestion seems similar but a bit more practical. I would +1 if I had enough rep.

Comment: If you think the answer is appropriate, please accept it so it can help understand that this was answered.